# The requested route [/add_action] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [*/*]

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spark-java

I get this no matter what I do. It does not happen on the GET right above it.

Java Spark:

```
package controllers;

import static spark.Spark.*;

import action.EmailReader;
import data.ActionReply;
import db.ActionsTable;
import spark.Request;
import spark.Response;
import spark.Route;
import utilities.JsonUtil;
import utilities.Tools;

public class ActionController {

    public ActionController() {
        get("/active_actions", (req, res) -> getActiveActions(res, req.queryParams("username")), JsonUtil.json());
        put("/add_action/", (req, res) -> putActiveActions(res, req.queryParams("username"), req.queryParams("data")), JsonUtil.json());
    }

    public ActionReply getActiveActions(Response resp, String username) {
        //Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        return new ActionReply("Success", true, "blahblahblah");
    }

    public ActionReply putActiveActions(Response resp, String username, String data) {
        //Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://siteA.com
        resp.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        ActionsTable.addFlowToEngine(username, data);
        return new ActionReply("Success", true, "Successful PUT.");
    }

}
```

AJAX Request:

```
var edata = editor().getValue();
        self.actions.push(edata);
        $.ajax({
               type: "PUT",
               dataType: "json",
               username: "dan_the_man",
               data: edata,
               url: "http://localhost:4567/add_action",
               success: function(data){
                 console.log(data);
               }
            });
```

Error:

```
507936 [qtp1182316047-39] INFO spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter - The requested route [/add_action/] has not been mapped in Spark for Accept: [*/*]
```

I also get:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://dan_the_man@localhost:4567/add_action/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Which I don't know why its doing this since I am setting the header to accept anything.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error on my server. It didn't make sense as my client WAS sending an Accept header. But it turned out the URL was wrong and the client was getting a 404.

The server was not logging that an invalid URL was being requested, but rather complaining of this mapping for the Accept header (to a non-existent resource).